# Use CSS3 variable and SASS rgba($hex, $alpha) function isn't working in Angular

Tags: angular, sass, css-variables, rgba

I build Angular project, and have following sass code:

```
// style.scss
:root {
  --style: rgba(#fff, 0.5);
}
```

Angular render CSS file (I use the CSS file in my project):

```
// style.css
:root {
  --style: rgba(#fff, 0.5);
}
```

The result what I want (or any other things that the browser can use).

```
:root {
  --style: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

I think `rgba()` is basic function of SASS. Did I do something wrong?

---

@angular/cli: 9.1.15

Comment: You are using a quite old version of Angular, it is out of support. I just tested this in an Angular 15 project, there it works properly.